# Tracking user's actions in Perl

Tags: perl, tracking, user-tracking

I am building a commercial web-based system on Perl and need to track all user's actions and behaviors.

I thought about using something like Log4perl or to write my own, maybe based on Redis.

Please share an idea of a nice solution for this problem, if you have one.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using a framework like [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/). It has logging built in and much much more.